# PL/SQL Using aliases and functions in the subquery of an insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm pretty new to PL/SQL, but I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the following :

```
   INSERT  INTO aTable (
   SELECT  FN_TO_VALUE(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) as alias1,
           FN_TO_VALUE(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) as alias2,
           FN_TO_VALUE(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) as alias3,
           c.field1, c.field2
   FROM    bTable b, cTable c
   WHERE   b.alias1= c.field3
   );
```

Given that **FN_TO_VALUE** is a function that returns the corresponding datatype that would be in the **aTable**.

I get the following error statements :

```
PL/SQL : SQL Statement ignored (that's located at the INSERT INTO line)
PL/SQL : ORA-00904: "B"."ALIAS1" invalid identifier
```

**ERRATA :**

- I had to modify the where clause from **WHERE   b.alias1= c.field1** to **WHERE   b.alias1= c.field3** because one of the solution provided by @Bob Jarvis wouldn't take into consideration other fields that might be required to link table bTable and cTable.

**SOLUTION :**

- I have opted for the following solution :

  ```
   INSERT  INTO aTable (
     SELECT b.alias1,
            b.alias2,
            b.alias3,
            c.field1,
            c.field2
     FROM cTable c, 
     (
       SELECT FN_TO_VALUE (field1, field2, field3) AS alias1,
              FN_TO_VALUE (field1, field2, field3) AS alias2,
              FN_TO_VALUE (field1, field2, field3) AS alias3
       FROM bTable 
     ) b
     WHERE b.alias1 = c.field3
  );
  ```

Comment: you either have to use a sub-select ( making that alias a WHERE-clausable column) or `WHERE FN_TO_VALUE(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) = c.field1` instead of `WHERE   b.alias1= c.field1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT  INTO aTable (
SELECT inner.alias1,
       inner.alias2,
       inner.alias3,
       inner.field1,
       inner.field2
  FROM (SELECT FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias1,
               FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias2,
               FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias3,
               c.field1,
               c.field2
          FROM bTable b, cTable c
         ) inner
 WHERE inner.alias1 = inner.field1
)
```

OR

```
INSERT  INTO aTable (
SELECT FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias1,
       FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias2,
       FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias3,
       c.field1,
       c.field2
  FROM bTable b, cTable c
 WHERE FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) = c.field1
   );
```

Comment: In the first example it looks to me like the WHERE clause should be removed from the inner SELECT, as `b` still doesn't have a field named `alias1` (as far as I can see in this contrived example).  The second looks like it should work, although the presence of a function call in the WHERE clause makes me nervous.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Yes ,thanks for correcting me for the first example ,and even i will also not suggest the second one ,calling the function twice for each row is not good practice.

Comment: About the first example, I haven't tested the code, but it seems to me that the join happens after the sub-select clause which is after the :

`inner WHERE inner.alias1 = iner.field1`

is that logical? I mean... I've never used INNER in such a way, aside from INNER JOINs

Comment: @dfive:inner is alias for the inline view ,if we use two inline view in this query and both having column column ,then to tell oracle which column from which view ,we need to give distinct name .Its just like table alias ,dnt be confused with KEYWORD INNER

Comment: @BobJarvis, I was just wondering about that INNER trick, what is it called and where can I find documentation about it? From what I see, inner is seen as a keyword... or are you just using inner as an alias?

Comment: I modified your code to the following, I think this more sense, although it did compile, I couldn't confirm that yours would work : 

`INSERT  INTO aTable (
SELECT tmpAlias.alias1,
       tmpAlias.alias2,
       tmpAlias.alias3,
       c.field1,
       c.field2
FROM cTable c, 
(
  SELECT FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias1,
         FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias2,
         FN_TO_VALUE (b.field1, b.field2, b.field3) AS alias3
  FROM bTable b
) tmpAlias
WHERE tmpAlias.alias1 = c.field1`

Comment: @DFIVE:yes your example is correct ,inner can be replaced with any string ,i dnt think before writing the code that inner confuses you so much :)  [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10939)

Comment: well `inner` is a keyword, I thought it was a feature that I wasn't aware of O_O, but all is good :D 
thanks ;)

Comment: wait, my way is highly inefficiency !!!! with my way, it will run FN_TO_VALUE against all the records instead of limiting it with a WHERE clause... this sucks...

Comment: @DFIVE - INNER is a keyword, but as with many things in SQL keywords can also be used as identifiers as long as their use doesn't confuse the parser.  :-)  In this case 'inner' is used as an alias for the inner SELECT, which can also be called an inline view.

Comment: I think the most confusing for me is how you joined the tables outside the inline view... I thought it was due to the INNER keyword...